# Sea Orm - Actix , vote system

Tags: rust, rust-actix, sea-orm

Django user here. I switching to Actix written in rust.
How to add or subtract 1 from existed value in database.
I have function

```
    post.vote = ActiveValue::Set(post.vote.into_wrapped_value() + 1);
```

and also tried

```
 post.vote = ActiveValue::Set(post.vote.take() + 1);
```

But i get error cannot subtract `{integer}` from `std::option::Option<i32>`

```
 post.vote = ActiveValue::Set(<sea_orm::ActiveValue<i32> as Into<T>>::into(post.vote) + 1);
```

Cannot find type `T` in this scope
so i add to `<T> to --> impl<T> PostRepository {`

the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
unconstrained type parameter

Any hint

Answer (score 1):

From documents https://www.sea-ql.org/SeaORM/docs/basic-crud/update/
People can first query exist value from database and then update it.

In your case, the codes could be like:

```
let pose = Pose::find_by_id(pose_id).one(db).await?.unwrap();
let vote = pose.vote;
let mut pose: pose::ActiveModel = pose.into();
pose.vote = Set(vote.map(|v| v + 1));

let pose: pose::Model = pose.update(db).await?;
```